# I'm encountering an issue when running `docker-compose up -d`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, chromebook

```
ronak15082002@penguin:~$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "ronak15082002_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "ronak15082002_mysql-db" with default driver
Pulling cosc304-mysql (mysql:8.0)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 79, in _execute
    output = subprocess.check_output(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-pass', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    data = store.get(registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 35, in get
    data = self._execute('get', server)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 93, in _execute
    raise errors.process_store_error(e, self.program)
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1107, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1088, in up
    return this.project.up(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 542, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build, silent=silent, cli=cli)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 360, in ensure_image_exists
    self.pull(silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1248, in pull
    return progress_stream.get_digest_from_pull(event_stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/progress_stream.py", line 102, in get_digest_from_pull
    for event in events:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1213, in _do_pull
    output = this.client.pull(repo, **pull_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 396, in pull
    header = auth.get_config_header(this, registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 47, in get_config_header
    authcfg = resolve_authconfig(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
    return authconfig.resolve_authconfig(registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
    cfg = this._resolve_authconfig_credstore(registry, store_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 280, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    raise errors.DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".')
```

I'm running docker-compose up -d, but I'm facing an issue with the following error message:

Docker Compose is creating a network and volume.

It then attempts to pull the "mysql:8.0" image.

The error occurs related to Docker credentials and the "docker-credential-pass" program.

The error message suggests an issue with GPG keys and the decryption process.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you share the dockerfile?

Comment: I can't find the docker file at all and don't really know how to

Comment: sorry my mistake , i meant the docker-compose file , can you share it

Comment: version: '3.3'
services:             
  cosc304-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: cosc304-mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '304testpw'            
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '304rootpw'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'  
    expose:
      - '3306'   
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./ddl:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
volumes:     
  mysql-db:

Comment: Can you update your question and put your docker compose there , this is not readable